# Display model's function in template

Tags: django

I am trying to integrate a data function to an existing system, I am basically new to Django. I am a bit confused with these two functions.

The existing code in models.py

```
@property
def some_func(self):
    return self.get_other_func_same_model_class()
```

The function that I want to add

```
def some_func2(self):
    return self.get_other_func_same_model_class()
```

views.py

```
class SchoolView(StandardPriceTierRequiredMixin,
                            SchoolStudentMixin,
                            ListView):
template_name = 'dashboard/grades.html'
url_name = 'edu:dashboard_grades'
paginate_by = None
model = GradeSubject
```

html

```
{% if some_func %}
{% if some_func.enrollee.enrollment_status == 'pending' %}
  <p>Sorry but <h1>{{ some_func.enrollee }} </h1> is still for pending status </p>
{% else %}
  <h1>{{ some_func.enrollee }}</h1>
  {% if some_func.enrollee.student_id %}
    <p>{% trans "Student ID" %}: {{ some_func.enrollee.student_id }} 
      {% if school_system.show_student_lrn %} 
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LRN
      {% endif %}
    </p>
    {{ student_details.block_section.name }}               
  {% endif %}
```

I am playing around with it right now to see how both functions behave, so I decided them to return the same function. Problem is, I can call the first function in to the template but I am unable to do so on the second func.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: please add your relevant `html` and `views.py`

Comment: I updated my post. My apologies

Comment: You need to show the code where you are attempting to call the second function and the result you see.

Answer (score 0):

from documentation:

> [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/glossary/#term-property)
>
> Also known as “managed attributes”, and a feature of Python since
> version 2.2. This is a neat way to implement attributes whose usage
> resembles attribute access, but whose implementation uses method
> calls.

So basic difference between normal method and method with `@property` decorator is that it will turns the method in to read-only attribute.
It's not core concept of django. If you look at any class method in python you will see that you can call the method with or without arguments whereas in attribute you can not perform any of those action

Read detail doc at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score -1):

Add the @property decorator for the second function also.

Comment: try calling it using the model instance for the model in which it is defined.

Comment: Tried it but still no display.